# Changing cufon fonts with dropdown and with livepreview

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, cufon

i make some script that will change cufon fonts from select options, and i would like it to be some kind of "live preview" for cufon fonts. So, when user select one font from dropdown menu, i would like to they see how it looks like. Currently, i did this, but have some problem, and don't know how to fix it. You can test my script here http://jsfiddle.net/djevrek/JVrpb/13/

Also, that script have google fonts preview, which works, and i want to make it possible for cufon too.

Answer (score 0):

I am bookmarking this b/c I really like where it is going.  What about using .live with change as the event?

http://api.jquery.com/live/

if that doesn't work then i have used the livequery plugin in similar situations

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

Comment: Dont know about that, but my preview works, but not on first change, after you change selector to other font, and after 2-3 seconds choose first one, you'll got what i want to do on first change :)

Comment: What's strange here is if I put alert in front of Cufon.replace, everything works perfect. http://jsfiddle.net/JVrpb/16/